# Integrating MSDynamicsDrawerViewController and storyboards in SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have been busting my head over this for some time. I am moving parts of UI created programmatically into storyboards to implement a bit of MVC in an iOS POC. The drawer view is implemented using a library called the MSDynamicsDrawerViewController. The entire drawer is implemented programmatically, which I tried to change to a static table view approach without any success. So I reverted back to the existing code.

However, I am facing problems while trying to integrate this drawer with a navigation controller and subsequent view controllers embedded in it. Eg: Once i click on an option "My Reports" in the drawer, it has to go to a My Reports table view controller defined using storyboard. This My Reports table view controller is embedded inside a navigation controller. the code is as below.

```
    case .MyReports:
                newPane = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyReportsViewID") as MyReportsViewController
                (newPane as MyReportsViewController).DrawerViewController = self.DrawerViewController
                println("MAIN_MENU: transition to MyReports Pane")

    if let pane = newPane {             
                let isAnimated = (self.currentVC != nil)
                // set panetype
                self.currentVC = type
//Am not sure of the below line, as the UINavigationController defined in the storyboard has to be used instead of defining a new UINavigationController
                let paneNavigator = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pane)
               self.DrawerViewController.setPaneViewController(paneNavigator, animated: isAnimated) {
                        println("MAIN_MENU: finished animating transition")
                }
            } else {
                println("MainMenuDrawer: there was an error transitioning to pane of type [\(type.toString())]")
            }
```

This entire code is wrapped inside a func transitionToViewController ( type: ViewControllerType), which is called on tapping an option in the drawer. The problem is I am getting an error "[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "MAW-aK-fxf-view-5t6-EI-G22" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'". My Reports view has a few navigation bar buttons which lead to other pages. Could any one give any suggestions as to how to solve this?